# Backbone model.save() sends attributes to the server in a weird way

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone and I set attributes like this:

```
  comment.set({
    commentable_id:   1,
    commentable_type: "Post",
    body:             "comment body",
    parent_id:        123,
    blabla:           'blabla'
  });
```

Then, when I try to save it like this:

```
comment.save({}, {[callbacks here]});
```

It sends data to the server like this:

```
{"commentable_id"=>"1",
 "commentable_type"=>"Post",
 "parent_id"=>"123",
 "blabla"=>"blabla",
 "body"=>"comment body"
 "comment"=> {"body"=>"comment body", "commentable_id"=>"1", "commentable_type"=>"Post"}}
```

So, as you can see, some data is duplicated inside the `comment` key, but not all. What I need is for all attribtues to be inside the `comment` key and for none to be outside of it.

The backbone model is absolutely empty:

```
  App.Models.Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: '/comments',

    initialize: function() {
    },

  });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps it's something on the server side? Can you please show the server side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you avoid `set` and just use `save` directly?

```
comment.save({
    comment: {
        commentable_id:   1,
        commentable_type: "Post",
        body:             "comment body",
        parent_id:        123,
        blabla:           "blabla"
    }
});
```